# Own Backend vs BaaS

Tags: iphone, ios, backend, parse-platform

I am trying to decide between two development firms. One wants to go with Parse while the other wants to build a backend. I would like to get feedback and reasons why building a backend or using a BaaS such as Parse, Stackmob is better in terms of scalability and performance.

For example let's use SnapChat a highly used app that handles millions of users and data requests. What would happen if a newly created app were to experience a large increase in users and data request. Would the backend be able to handle this? Would I be looking to have it fixed shortly after the increase in users?

Answer (score 8):

Something like Parse.com gives you a lot of value for very little capital investment. With BaaS, all of the gory details of infrastructure management are hidden. Deployment, system capacity issues, system availability, system security, database administration and a myriad of other task simply go away when using a good BaaS. Parse.com for instance, uses Amazon Web Services and elastic load balancing to dynamically add more capacity to the system as usage increases. This is the nirvana of capacity management.

Parse.com is a special kind of BaaS. Parse.com's intended purpose is to be a light-weight back-end back-end for mobile apps. I believe Parse.com is a very good mobile backend-as-a-service ([MBaaS - link to a Forrester article on the subject](http://blogs.forrester.com/michael_facemire/12-04-25-mobile_backend_as_a_service_the_new_lightweight_middleware)).

That said, there are times when Parse.com is not the right solution. Estimate the number of users for the application and the number of HTTP requests and average user would send in a day. Parse.com charges by the number of transactions. The Pro Plan has these limits:

- 15 million HTTP requests per month
- Burst limit of 40 requests per second

Many small transactions can result in a higher cost to the app owner. For example, if there are 4,500 users, each sending 125 HTTP requests to Parse.com per day, then you are already looking at 16,850,000 requests every 30 days. Parse.com also offers a higher level of service called Parse Enterprise. Details about this plan are not published.

The services provided by a BaaS/MBaaS save much time and energy on the part of the application developer, but impose some constraints. For example, the response time of Parse.com might be too slow for your needs. Unless you upgrade to their Enterprise plan, you have no control over response times. You currently have no control over where your app is hosted (Parse apps are presently run out of Amazon's data centers in Virginia, I believe).

The BaaS providers I have looked at do not provide quality-of-service metrics. Even if they did, there is no community agreement on what metrics would be meaningful. You just get what you get and hope it is good enough for your needs.

An application is a good candidate for an MBaaS if :

1. It is simple or the application logic can run entirely on the client (phone, tablet...)
2. It is impossible to estimate the number of users or the number of users *could* be huge.
3. You don't want a big upfront capital investment.
4. You don't want to hire infrastructure specialists to handle capacity/security/data/recovery/network engineering.
5. Your application does not have strict response time requirements.

Parse's best use case is the iPhone developer who wrote a game and needs to store the user's high scores, but knows nothing about servers. That said, complex application like [Hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com/) are using Parse. Have a look at [Parse.com's portfolio of case studies](https://parse.com/customers/case_study). Can you imagine your application in that portfolio or is it very different from those apps?

Even if a BaaS is not the right solution, a PaaS or IaaS might be. Look at Rackspace and AWS. In this day and age, buying hardware and running a data center is tough to justify.

Answer (score 2):

BaaS providers like [apiomat](http://apiomat.com) or parse have to handle the requests of thousands of apps. Every app can have lots of users there. The providers are forced to make the system absolutely secure and scalable because if there are any issues about one of those points it will be the end of their business... Building scalable secure backends on your own is not as easy a you would expect. Those companys mentioned above have invested some man-years in that.